# Delete every n-th file Python

Tags: python

I'm looking to delete every 10th file from a folder using a Python script. I looked around and found this code:

```
import os
l = os.listdir('/Users/myname/Desktop/TBD')

for n in l[::10]:
    os.unlink(n)
```

I created a Python script for this then ran it in terminal using

```
python filename.py
```

And this is what I get in return:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Pic-1.jpg'
```

The folder I point to with the code is the folder containing 1000 photos. It's reading the name of the first folder but isn't going through with the delete process. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `listdir()` is returning you just names of entries in specified folder, without path element. So when you try to unlink these files, you try to do that in context of current working directory, not in `/Users/myname/Desktop/TBD/` as you should. Simply add path to each filename you want to unlink or ensure `/Users/myname/Desktop/TBD` is your working directory.

Additionally, for general safety you should check if element you are about to unlink is in fact a file, not i.e. directory or anything else:

```
import os

dir_to_clean = '/Users/myname/Desktop/TBD'
l = os.listdir(dir_to_clean)

for n in l[::10]:
    target = dir_to_clean + '/' + n
    if os.path.isfile(target):
        os.unlink(target)
```

Comment: So I popped the code in and it runs. It appears to delete photo 1-10 and leave the remaining. I'm looking to have it delete 10 photos at a time.. So for example: given a folder of 100 photos after running the script, there should be 10 left. I realized that the code just specifies to take out "n" photos, so it isn't iterating across.

Comment: @D500, your question is about deleting every 10th file from a folder, so there should be 90 left out of 100 -> [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100].

Comment: Just changed the question. I changed the code to n=2 instead of 10 and ran it three times assuming I'd get every 8th photo. However, the code works in a weird way. It isn't deleting every 2nd photo.. It looks like on the first pass, it deletes every 2nd photo, then on the second pass, it preserves the first two files and begins deleting every 2nd photo afterwards. This repeats.. Why does it work like this?

Comment: don't change the question once it is answered! StackOverflow is not a discussion forum. [Accept the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) that addresses your problem and if you got another one, simply post another question

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the advice!